# Неведомый баг при построении маршрута яндекс карт

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

    var startPlacemark, endPlacemark, multiRoute
    let coord_start = ['71.406975', '51.089227'];
    // Стоимость за километр.
    var DELIVERY_TARIFF = 100,
        // Минимальная стоимость.
        MINIMUM_COST = 200,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: coord_start,
            zoom: 9,
            controls: []
        }),
        zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
            options: {
                size: 'small',
                float: 'none',
                position: {
                    bottom: 145,
                    right: 10
                }
            }
        });
    //  var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest');

    var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest', {
        provider: {
            suggest: (function(request, options) {
                return ymaps.suggest("Нур-Султан," + request);

            })
        }
    });

    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            // Будет производиться поиск только по топонимам.
            provider: 'yandex#map',
            noPlacemark: true
        }
    });
    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);


    startPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coord_start, {
        balloonContent: 'Кабанбай Батыра, 62',
        //  iconContent: "Алматы, Розыбакиева, 11"
    }, {
        //    preset: "islands#blueStretchyIcon",
        // Отключаем кнопку закрытия балуна.
        // balloonCloseButton: false,
        // Балун будем открывать и закрывать кликом по иконке метки.
        hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
    });

    // событие поиска searchControl
    searchControl.events.add('resultselect', function(e) {
        var results = searchControl.getResultsArray();
        var selected = searchControl.getSelectedIndex();
        coord_end = results[selected].geometry.getCoordinates();

        addRoute(coord_start, coord_end)
    })


    // Создание метки.
    function createPlacemark(coords) {
        return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
            iconCaption: 'поиск...'
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
            draggable: false
        });
    }

    myMap.events.add('click', function(e) {
        //  получить координаты клика
        let coord_end = e.get('coords');

        //Добавить точку на карту
        //addEndPlacemark(coord_end)

        //вывести маршрут
        addRoute(coord_start, coord_end)

    });

    function addEndPlacemark(coord_end) {
        //   переместить метку на новые координаты

        //   Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
        if (endPlacemark) {
            endPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(end_coords);
        }
        // Если нет – создаем.
        else {
            endPlacemark = createPlacemark(end_coords);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(endPlacemark);
            // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
            // endPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {

            // });
        }
        coord_end = endPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates()
        getAddress(coord_end);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(endPlacemark);
    }

    // Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
    function getAddress(coords) {
        endPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
        ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function(res) {
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);

            endPlacemark.properties
                .set({
                    // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                    iconCaption: [
                        // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                        firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                        // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                        firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                    ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                    // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                    balloonContent: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
                });
        });
    }

    function addRoute(coord_start, coord_end) {

        if (multiRoute) {

            multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([coord_start, coord_end]);
        } else {
            multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({

                // Описание опорных точек мультимаршрута.
                referencePoints: [
                    coord_start,
                    coord_end
                ],
                // Параметры маршрутизации.
                params: {
                    // Ограничение на максимальное количество маршрутов, возвращаемое маршрутизатором.
                    results: 1
                }
            }, {
                // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
                boundsAutoApply: true
            });
            myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
        }

        //расчет и вывод значений
        multiRoute.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function() {
            let distance = multiRoute.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance")
            let distance_km = Math.round(distance.value / 1000)
            let price = calculate(distance_km)

            addResult(distance_km, price)

            console.log(distance_km)
            console.log(price)
        });

    }

    myMap.controls.add(zoomControl);
    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(startPlacemark);


    // Функция, вычисляющая стоимость доставки.
    function calculate(routeLength) {
        return Math.max(routeLength * DELIVERY_TARIFF, MINIMUM_COST);
    }

    function addResult(distance, price) {
        let el_distance = document.querySelector('#km')
        let el_summ = document.querySelector('#summ')
        el_distance.innerHTML = distance
        el_summ.innerHTML = price
    }

  
document.getElementById('suggest').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        let address = e.target.value.trim() // убирает пробелы в начале и конце
        geocode(address)
          console.log(address)
    })
  
  

    function geocode(adress) {
        console.log('geocode')
        // Забираем запрос из поля ввода.
        var request = adress //$('#suggest').val();
        // Геокодируем введённые данные.
        ymaps.geocode(request).then(function(res) {
            var obj = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                error, hint;
           console.log(obj);
            if (obj) {
                // Об оценке точности ответа геокодера можно прочитать тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/reference/precision-docpage/
                switch (obj.properties.get('metaDataProperty.GeocoderMetaData.precision')) {
                    case 'exact':
                        break;
                    case 'number':
                    case 'near':
                    case 'range':
                        error = 'Неточный адрес, требуется уточнение';
                        hint = 'Уточните номер дома';
                        break;
                    case 'street':
                        error = 'Неполный адрес, требуется уточнение';
                        hint = 'Уточните номер дома';
                        break;
                    case 'other':
                    default:
                        error = 'Неточный адрес, требуется уточнение';
                        hint = 'Уточните адрес';
                }
            } else {
                error = 'Адрес не найден';
                hint = 'Уточните адрес';
            }

            // Если геокодер возвращает пустой массив или неточный результат, то показываем ошибку.
            if (error) {
                showError(error);
                //   showMessage(hint);
            } else {
                console.log('Результат поиска')

                coord_end = obj.geometry.getCoordinates()

                addRoute(coord_start, coord_end)
                // console.log()
                //   showResult(obj);
            }
        }, function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        })

    }

    function showError(message) {
        alert(message)
    }

}
```

```css
.input {
height:40px;
 width:100%;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=b9cb3120-b3f9-42d1-9514-9bbc06532690&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;coordorder=longlat"></script>
<input name="address" type="text" id="suggest" value="" class="input">

<div id="summ"></div>
<div id="km"></div>

<div id="map" style="height: 300px;margin-bottom:30px;"></div>
```

Чтоб увидеть проблему надо ввести в input
187 20 и выбрать из выпадающего списка
Казахстан, Нур-Султан (Астана), улица 187, 20
Почему то он пишет что адрес не найден.
Но если потом удалить в конце пробел и нажать enter то прокладывает и расчитывает.
Также если вставить сразу в инпут адрес
Казахстан, Нур-Султан (Астана), улица 187, 20
То тоже расчитывает.
Надо чтоб человек выбрав адрес из выпадающего списка, проходил расчет.

Если пользоваться поиском на карте яндекса, то считает все идеально.
Ввожу 187 20, выбираю 20 дом на улице 187 и отлично прокладывает. Но нужно именно чтоб с того поля считал. Чтоб понять ошибку, смотрите видео.

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/0KjJBaFdROdUDQ

Неведомая ошибка, найти причину не могу....

Answer (score 1):

Геокодер любит нормально форматированный адрес, а не чепуху вида "187 20". А ему, нажимая Enter, вы скармливаете именно это, в отличие от саджеста, которому подставляете хотя бы город с запятой (но без пробела).

Добавьте в строку геокодирования форматированное начало **"Казахстан, Нур-Султан (Астана), улица "** и ошибка уйдёт:

```
document.getElementById('suggest').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    let address = "Казахстан, Нур-Султан (Астана), улица " + e.target.value.trim()
    geocode(address)
    console.log(address)
})
```

А выбор подсказки Саджеста стоит обрабатывать [встроенным методом API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView.html#event_detail):

```
suggestView.events.add('select', function (event) {
    var address = event.get('item').value;
    geocode(address);
    console.log(address);
})
```